# Make iFrame expand to the left

Tags: html, css, iframe, styles

I'm making a UI that lives inside an iFrame and can be embedded into HTML pages. The UI contains a horizontal menu of variable length. Think something like:

Home - Login - About - Help

But where the length / number of elements of the menu is subject to change. The UI exists on the **top right of each page** it is embedded on. What I'd like to happen is when I add an element to the menu, let's say "Contact Us", I want the iFrame to expand left to accomodate the extra element.

Right now the menu is structured with multiple divs styled with

`display: inline-block;`

but I've also tried it using UL and LIs.

What's making this complicated is that I don't want the iFrame's width to be the whole page, I just want it to be big enough to contain the menu. But if I don't set the width explicitly when I add new elements, instead of lining up horizontally they get pushed to the next line.

So when I add a new element (Contact Us) I want it to look like this:

```
Home - Login - About - Help - Contact Us
```

But it ends up looking like

```
Home - Login - About - Help 
- Contact Us
```

(Remember this is all happening inside of an iFrame that is `position: fixed;` to the top right of every page)

What I'm trying to figure out is how to make the iFrame expand to the left instead of pushing new elements down to the next line. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you put up a code example?

Answer (score 0):

As long as both pages are on the same domain, you could use the `window.frameElement` property in javascript to set the size on the iFrame element from inside the menu page.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this little lib that handles iFrame resizing on both axis.

**https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer**